# JavaScript modification to add selection to the url as a query string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic JavaScript that mimic's the following solution [ see [link](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_create_class_filter.htm) ]. What it does is it displays in a drop down the value taken from a CSS element, and populates the drop down. Pending on what the user selects, it will display just elements from the CSS class as code shows below.

Let's say I would like to send out a url that already has the options preselected, I'm not sure how to approach this meaning how to modify existing script to do just this. I presume I'll rely on populating a query string, but any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $tagList = $('#tag-list'),
    optionArr = [];
  console.log($tagList);

  $("#demo-list li a").each(function(index, item) {
    $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function(i, option) {
      if ($.inArray(option, optionArr) == -1) {
        $tagList.append('<option value="' + option + '">' + option.replace('-', ' ').replace('_', ' ') + '</option>');
        optionArr.push(option);
      }
    });
  });
  $tagList.on('change', function() {
    var selection = $tagList.val();
    if (selection == "all") {
      $('#demo-list li a').show();
    } else {
      $('#demo-list li a').hide();
      $('#demo-list li a.' + selection).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were missing jQuery in the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, that was added to the head section. The code works fine, its just that I'm looking to modify it so the filter options are saved in the url.